# the grammar about `adv adv` as 'too quickly'

Tags: grammar

I read such a sentence from my error report

> WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly

The first time to notice explicitly that the `adv adv` grammar structure.

However, it might be awkward to say  'respawn extremely extremely quickly'.
Naturally  to say `very quickly` or `too quickly'

Are there such limits in grammar that exclusively solely the special  adv as  "very and too" could be used before another adv ?

Where could consult the details of the `adv adv` grammar with?

Comment: Katy's answer is good, as for where you can find more information about it, there's another answer here https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/195550/87779 which may lead you to more information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, **it's not a grammar rule** that you can't stack adverbs other than "too" or "very."

These are all grammatical sentences:

- She spoke **barely audibly**.
- He worked **especially slowly**.
- The dog barked **very rapidly**.
- The sky thundered **rather formidably**.
- I saw them **just recently**.
- She runs **ridiculously quickly**.
- The guitarist plays **amazingly well.**

These sentences, where the adverbs are next to each other, but a comma stands in for the conjunction "and" are also grammatical:

- The sun was blazingly, agonizingly hot.
- The pot was symmetrically, colorfully painted.

As a **matter of style**, however, excessive adverb use is generally discouraged.

Comment: Of course, you can have "excessive" adverb use without stacking adverbs, and you can stack adverbs in a way that is not excessive (e.g. your first example of "barely audibly" is fine because both words are essential to the meaning).

Comment: @Kevin Oh, absolutely. That said, an anti-adverb stickler would probably recommend "she whispered" instead.

Comment: Excessive use is discouraged, whatever you are using. But only by those who don't like excesses.